# Printing random set strings?

Tags: c#, random, console-application

How would I make a console write several random strings, for example

```
string Test1 = "Test Hello!";
string Test2 = "Test2 Hello hows your day!";
string Test3 = "How are you today sir?";
```

How would I make a program that randomly outputs those strings?

Comment: obviously you need to have those data somewhere or you have to hard code them in array. [and get random number](https://www.dotnetperls.com/random)

Answer (score 1):

The solution is pretty easy :

```
Random rnd = new Random();

//List of all your strings in which we will select a random index
List<string> sentences =  new List<string>
{
     "Test Hello!",
     "Test2 Hello hows your day!",
     "How are you today sir?"
};

//Write one of the sentences randomly thanks to [rnd.Next][1]
Console.WriteLine(sentences[rnd.Next(sentences.Count)]);
```

Comment: of course it depends how random the OP wants :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that will print a random string from a list x amount of times:

```
var random = new Random();

var sentences = new List<string>
{
    "Test Hello!",
    "Test2 Hello hows your day!",
    "How are you today sir?"
};

Console.Write("How many random sentences would you like to print?: ");

var count = 0;

// Convert user input into the integer count variable, and continually print an error message 
// if the input is not an integer or if the integer is less than 0
while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out count) || count < 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter a positive integer: ");
}

// Print out a random sentence for x (count) amount of times.
while (count > 0)
{
    // Will generate an index within the range of the list
    var index = random.Next(0, sentences.Count() - 1);

    Console.WriteLine(sentences[index]);
    count--;
}

// Prevents the console from closing after the program is done executing.
Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit the application...");
Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can do

```
        Random random = new Random();
        string[] testcases = new[] {

            "Test Hello!",
            "Test2 Hello hows your day!",
            "How are you today sir?"
        };

        Console.WriteLine(testcases[random.Next(0, testcases.Length)]);
        Console.WriteLine(testcases[random.Next(0, testcases.Length)]);
        Console.WriteLine(testcases[random.Next(0, testcases.Length)]);
```